# How to convert a react-native-like js file to plain javascript file?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, browserify

I want to convert a react-native-like js file to plain javascript file so that it can be execute by JavaScriptCore. I know browserify can convert Node-like file to plain javascript file. But when I execute :

`browserify script.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]`

it returns an error:

```
Cannot find module 'ActivityIndicator' from '/home/yjy/Work/react_native/Webview/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native'
```

The script.js like follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>HelloWorld.....</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to copy the ActivityIndicator.js file to this folder,but it still report the same error.How can I solve this problem? What's more,how does react native solve bundle these modules to a bundle file? What's the difference between index.android.bundle file and the executable plain js file?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could hit the packager url with curl to get the bundle. The bundle is just 'browserifed' code that can run in JSCore. It probably won't be very readable.